# anchor tag is not loading in one frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load anchor tag url in one particular frame.
I tried multiple options using google. but, couldnt get proper result.
can you please help me how to load href url in one particular frame

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<A href="index.html" target="display">Homepage</A>
<FRAMESET cols="150,*">
   <FRAME name="display" src="main.html">
</FRAMESET>
</body>
</html
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally considered a bad idea to use frames in modern web pages. However, you can use the technique described in this article to suit your needs:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/iframes/qt/target-links-iframes-and-frames.htm

Comment: hi Fiippos. this is for Iframe. and above code is not working for Frame